# PHP Regex won't match

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to php development (I'm learning by myself like many I think) and regex, I have the following function among others in a php file:

```
function func($data) {

  $posData = preg_replace( '/([^.0-9]+)/', '', $data); // This should remove everything but periods and numbers.

  if ( preg_match( '/^([01][0-9]|20|[01][0-9][.][0-9]{1,2}|0[.][0-9]{1,2})\z/' , $posData ) ) {
    return $posData;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Which is supposed to match eg: 20 | 0.25 | 12 | 08.54 | 15.6 , this should not match 0, 7.12, anything higher than 20 or with a period at the end. If I check this on regex101.com it works fine, if I run this on my site from the same page with no function and pre-established data it works fine. But when I send data trough a form and use a php file like this:

```
<?php
   include_once'/path/to/functions.php';

   $text = $_POST['text'];

   if ( $a = func($text) !== false ) {
      $b = func($text);
      echo $b;
   }
   else {
      echo "Failed";
   }
?>
```

It matches 20 | 01 | 12 and also 99 (which should not be) but does not match eg: 0.58 | 12.45 | 08.65 , and I can't get it to work. I just don't understand why is this happening.

PD: I'm not a native english speaker, so I'm sorry for any misspelling or any language syntax mistake. Also if someone could help me make my regex a bit faster or shorter would be appreciated very much.

Comment: `[^.0-9]` corresponds to not any symbol except of new line. Escape the dot `\.`

Comment: "If I check this on regex101.com it works fine" -- - does it? http://regex101.com/r/yK2cX1/1

Comment: @Cheery: does not need to be when used as a character class. The first statement about `[^.0-9]` is false as well

Comment: @zerkms The pipes are the eg separators. I know it would not match.

Comment: @Victor Tello: what do you mean by it works on regex101 then? Could you show something that *works*?

Comment: @zerkms http://regex101.com/r/yK2cX1/2, it should be that way.

Comment: "but does not match eg: 0.58" --- it does http://regex101.com/r/yK2cX1/3

Comment: @zerkms That's what I'm trying to say. It works on regex101, but if I use that on my site with a form that contains a number and try to check for that pattern it returns false even if the number is right.

Comment: @VictorTello it works in php as well: http://ideone.com/MX0fS2 Could you please provide a small self-contained piece of php code that could reproduce the actual issue?

Comment: This part of a line: $a = func($text) should be: ($a = func($text))

Comment: @zerkms I know it does, but try to send from one php file a post with the number and fetch that number in another php file to run the function. And the function has to be included from a different path. I'm so sorry this is turning out so confusing.

Comment: @Victor Tello: "I know it does" --- if it works, what your question is about? If the exact code does not work in some circumstances the chances are you have some other data, not what you *expect*.

Comment: @user3629249 Hi, why is that? Please explain.

Comment: @VictorTello because of http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php (but it doesn't matter, since you're not using `$a`)

Comment: @zerkms I'm getting the right data, I also echo the post data before running the function. It's just so rare that I can't figure it out.

Comment: `var_dump(func($text))`. "I also echo the post data" --- don't `echo` but `var_dump` when debugging

Comment: @zerkms I tried var_dump(func($text)) and this is what I get bool(false) when I send 01.58 :S !

Comment: @Victor Tello: well, it means that your code does not match to what you've shown to us, since your code does work: http://ideone.com/4pagM5

Comment: @zerkms The full code is a bit larger. If there any way I can show it to you without posting it?

Comment: @Victor Tello: there is - you can hire me to debug your code.

Comment: @zerkms That's not an option for me. I'm from Venezuela and I can't make online payments or anything like that. And besides I do not want to pay anyone for that. Anyway thank you very much for trying to help.

Comment: is the locale set for English?

Comment: @user3629249 this is what I get from locale_get_default() --en_US_POSIX, so I guess yes. Haven't read about locale at all.

Answer (score -1):

Well I really do not know why, but I solved all this problem by echoing a javascript alert message containing the text variable every time I make a step on my function. Then I uploaded my functions page to my server, closed my browser, cleaned all browser data, Then I open it again and tried to run the form check with one bad data eg: 99, it alerted through all the process. Then I tried with one good data eg: 08.20 and it did not alerted any message and the function output was false. So I figured out that something was wrong with the page cache or something like that (I wasn't sure what was it) so I decided to include some html tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
  </head>
  <body>
     <?php

        // Include functions.php
        // Get POST values.
        // POST data checking code
        // Echo checking result

     ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

And problem solved. If anyone can explain to me why that happened, it would be very helpful.